# Restkit nested Object mapping issue

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to populate two core data entities by using the following json structure.

```
{
  "fldrs": [
    {
      "FldName": "Messages",
      "FldID": "Messages",
      "PrntFldID": null,
      "UnRdCunt": "0",
      "Cunt": "0",
      "IsDflt": "True",
      "FldIconID": null,
      "SubFldrs": [
        {
          "FldName": "Compose",
          "FldID": "INDV9",
          "PrntFldID": "Messages",
          "UnRdCunt": "0",
          "Cunt": "0",
          "IsDflt": "False",
          "FldIconID": null,
          "SubFldrs": null,
          "tasksLists": null
        },
        {
          "FldName": "Inbox",
          "FldID": "INDV10",
          "PrntFldID": "Messages",
          "UnRdCunt": "2",
          "Cunt": "12",
          "IsDflt": "True",
          "FldIconID": null,
          "SubFldrs": null,
          "tasksLists": null
        }
      ],
      "tasksLists": null
    },
    {
      "FldName": "My Tasks",
      "FldID": "My Tasks",
      "PrntFldID": null,
      "UnRdCunt": "0",
      "Cunt": "0",
      "IsDflt": "False",
      "FldIconID": null,
      "SubFldrs": [
        {
          "FldName": "Pending",
          "FldID": "INDV1",
          "PrntFldID": "My Tasks",
          "UnRdCunt": "9",
          "Cunt": "9",
          "IsDflt": "False",
          "FldIconID": null,
          "SubFldrs": null,
          "tasksLists": null
        }
      ],
      "tasksLists": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here 'SubFldrs' are the child entity of 'flds'.

Here is data model I am using

[image]

And the following are the model classes using

```
@class ParentFolder;

@interface SubFolder : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fldId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fldName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * isDefault;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * msgCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prntFolderId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * unreadCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ParentFolder *subFolder_folder;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class SubFolder;

@interface ParentFolder : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fldId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fldName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *folder_SubFolder;
@end

@interface ParentFolder (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFolder_SubFolderObject:(SubFolder *)value;
- (void)removeFolder_SubFolderObject:(SubFolder *)value;
- (void)addFolder_SubFolder:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFolder_SubFolder:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

And the Restkit Mapping is done by following code

```
RKObjectMapping* subFolderMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SubFolder class] ];
    [subFolderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                           @"FldName":   @"fldName",
                                                           @"FldID":   @"fldId",
                                                           @"IsDflt":   @"isDefault",
                                                           @"UnRdCunt":   @"unreadCount",
                                                           @"Cunt":   @"msgCount",
                                                           @"PrntFldID":   @"prntFolderId"
                                                           }];

    RKObjectMapping* folderMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ParentFolder class] ];
    [folderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"FldID":  @"fldId",
                                                        @"FldName": @"fldName"
                                                        }];

    [folderMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"subFolder"
                                                                                   toKeyPath:@"SubFldrs"
                                                                                 withMapping:subFolderMapping]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:folderMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@"fldrs"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    return responseDescriptor;
```

The parent entity (ParentFolder) is populating as required, but child entity (SubFolder) is always empty.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have the keys in the wrong order when you create the relationship mapping:

```
[folderMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"SubFldrs"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"subFolder"
                                                                            withMapping:subFolderMapping]];
```

Comment: Child table is populated with null values and having only one record available. Please help me out.

Comment: Just noticed you show a Core Data model and talk about tables, but you use `NSObject` subclasses and object mappings. Are you using Core Data or not?

Comment: Sorry, actually those are NSManagedObject subclasses only. I will edit my question. Now I am able to save the data correctly with your suggestion. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: It would be good if you can correct your mappings in the question too (for entity instead of object) to help people who look at this in the future.